# A society without metal

Tags: society, medieval, metals

**What would a medieval society without access to metal look like? How would things like wagons, weapons, coinage, and tools be different?**

"Medieval" in this sense would mean something like feudal Japan, medieval Europe, or the Muslim/Arab nations during the Crusades period. Technology is different without metal, but they understand the basics of medicine (like disease) but not concepts like bacteria or genetics, they have roads, the wheel, tamed animals, boats capable of at least limited ocean voyages, farming, semi-accurate cartography, books written by hand on paper or paper-like materials, some form of carpentry or stone work that enables fortifications like castles, etc.

Other Conditions:

- Metal still exists in the world (and in plants/animals/people). It just isn't used by this society for anything
- No fantasy creatures like dragons or dwarves. Only real animals and plants
- Topography, geography, and climate can be anything found on Earth
- Magic exists, but I'm looking at how things would be without magic. Explaining the magic system would be unnecessarily involved for this question. I can take your ideas and add magic to it

([Related: Warfare without Metal](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11042/warfare-without-metal))

Comment: What defines, to you, the idea of a "medieval society"? The idea is heavily entwined with the technology level and that requires a lot of metal.

Comment: A great question. Edit incoming for clarity.

Comment: They understand disease but not bacteria?

Comment: By "disease" I mean they know something makes people sick, but don't know the distinction between bacteria and viruses, nor definitively how people get sick. Only that people with mice and mosquitoes get sick more often, and other such readily-observable information.

Comment: Some processes and tools that would be impeeded by not using metals, could be helped by using ceramic materials.

Comment: Related and posibly overlapping with "[Technology without heavier elements](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/11408/3202)".

Comment: @Samuel A great connection there. Much of that discussion focuses around lighter metals, but still some neat ideas to be found there.

Comment: See also MesoAmerica: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesoamerica

Comment: What, society without METAL? You mean they all listen to Miley Cyrus? :D

Comment: A harder question if figuring out how a human society could advance that far without discovering the usefulness of metals. Also consider cutting stone without metal takes a really long time, so they will not have much in the way of fortification.

Answer (score 12):

## Substitutes

You can make this work with substitutes. Armor can be made of items other than metal. For instance, [Cuir Bouilli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boiled_leather), which is speculated to be the [origin of cuirasses](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lxkb-a0f9Wc), is boiled leather. It gives a "plastic-like" leather armor, which can be an effective defense. Padded armor was popular throughout the medieval period as well, especially for archers, as it retains mobility and is a cheaper alternative to other armors.

[Obsidian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsidian#Historical_use) have been used since time immemorial, at least before written records. This stone is used for knives, arrow heads, and other items. Obsidian is even used by modern surgeons, as the blade can be much more even (and therefore better at cutting) than metal blades. Durability is an issue with obsidian. [Stone tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_tool) of other types are well documented, and can be used for many things.

[Coinage and economy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monetary_system) would be a little different. Metal coins were used because metal was valuable, and therefore the money had intrinsic value. In the absence of metal coins, other valuables could be traded. The natives of Aruba used round stones for their coinage. (I know this from their museum!) There are also other economies which do not rely on cash. They could use one of those systems. (My personal favorite are [gift-economies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EaxjxICgahc)!)

Wagons can be made almost entirely of wood. In the place of nails, you can use wooden pegs. Old furniture (antiques) can often be found with wooden pegs instead of nails. Joints can be made with rope lashings, or slots in the wood. No metal can be worked around. The fact that wood warps when wet can cause lots of problems. Wagon wheels would need to be sealed or treated often in order to avoid cracking and warping.

Comment: Hadn't thought about the warping wood problem (and expansion/contraction based on weather, too). Good link for Cuir Bouilli as well.

Comment: of course shaping wood is going to take much longer, and precision woodworking is right out.  Wagons are going to be rare or small.

Answer (score 8):

Well there are plenty of societies without metal out there, or at least traditionally had none.  The Inuit, the Aborigine, many tribes in Borneo and South America.

One of the things about metal is that it is stronger than wood and is more shapable than stone, not as brittle as bone etc.  So without metal you are left to make tools out of the other three options.

So bows are not going to change much, the metal arrow heads are more important to pierce heavy armor, but now they are limited to boiled leather, which while still tough doesn't need as much of a punch as steel, unless you have it in layers.

instead of swords, you will have clubs/maces.  Lances/pikes can still have sharpened points or stone heads.

Bones make good weapons too.

Wood, Stone and bones all can make a multitude of tools, often one can be made that we normally see in metal, but will many times have a different weakness.  It's hard to make wood sharp, but it can have great points and it works well as a frame.  Bones are harder and stronger than wood, can be made sharp but don't hold an edge well and are difficult to sharpen.  Stone is heavy, and easy to find.  Practice can be used to make many different kinds of tools.  Using sharp stones to shape the other materials.

So Many tools might never be made because the effort put into them might not be worth the value one gets out of them.  A stone sword it fairly pointless, since one good swing at another stone sword, and both will shatter to nothing and weeks/months of effort gone.  Why build a two story house when you will need to cut and shape much larger trees by hand, when you can just make another building nearby?

Economy?  I suspect it will be primarily trade/barter.  However, anything that is agreed upon can be used as currency.  [Sea Shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_money) have been used in the past, and so have rocks.  I also suspect precious gems could work well too.

Comment: Interesting concept, that some tools/buildings would never occur do to difficulties in production. Any thoughts on transportation, coinage, or day-to-day life that would be different?

Comment: There are also obsidian/glass based cutting tools, just to round out the set of materials for toolmaking.

Comment: @Dan I expect that most commerce would be trade/barter, and 'coinage' would be things that occurred naturally, sea shells, gem stones etc.

Comment: @Green yes, I was kind of counting obsidian with the 'stones' but I suppose it has enough utility of it's own that it should be pointed out.

Comment: Cutting stone would be impeded by not having metal but you could still bake clay to make bricks and cook lime to make mortar. So making buildings would not be as hard as you imply.

Comment: @AdamNicholls I guess I didn't mean to imply that building would be so hard as to be not worth it, just that some things won't be done because the work isn't worth the effort (unless your rich).  But yes bricks are one way to build as well.  Cutting stone for buildings can also be done without metal tools, but it's harder and the need/pay would be greater

Comment: @bowlturner Without metal, stone cutting seems like it would take forever and be realy inconsistent. Making ceramic materials, taking natural materials and then burning/cook them under high temperatures, seems like one of the best way to make strong products.

Comment: @AdamNicholls I don't argue that.  But people DID cut stone without metal tools.  Not all stone is as hard as granite.  Some used freezing water to help speed things along.

Comment: @Green: Obsidian is natural glass; you can chip it to make fine cutting tools, but the invention of artificial glass (or the melting of obsidian) will be quite a revolution, similar to the leap from copper tools to bronze.

Comment: @Beta, I agree. Do we have the technology to make remelted / artificial obsidian tools now?

Comment: @Green: Some people practice the ancient craft of knapping obsidian (and flint) today. Obsidian scalpels are superior to steel in some respects, but as far as I know they are manufactured using modern techniques (i.e. with metal tools). The only use of molten obsidian I've heard of is sculpture using "new" obsidian (you grab some liquid glass right from the volcano and manipulate it with steel tongs as it cools). But I think instead of melting obsidian, our fictional people would use silica sand (before moving on to quartz...).

Comment: What advantages would artificial obsidian have?

Comment: "one good swing at another stone sword, and both will shatter to nothing" - Well, edge-to-edge contact with metal swords will produce a major dent in both swords, and subsequent heavy impacts may well cause the damaged blade to break at the defect. That's why medieval knights carried shields, and why Hollywood movies are crap at history.

Answer (score 3):

In reality the same but everything would take longer and cost more (in terms of absolute calorific cost, prices would be the same because it would all be relatively the same). For example a wagon is wagon shaped because it works, the tools are different but the products are going to be very similar, there are certain pieces of technology that are now "top end" that weren't, the double bow spring for suspension since leafsprings are out, bricks and mortar over steel frame, that kind of thing, but most of that only comes late in, or after the time period you're interested in emulating. In terms of weapons and armour I'd look to the Aztec and Maya as a guide to the science of the possible in that arena. Coinage isn't a necessity of the time period you want to emulate but it helps, shells, beads, letters of credit in a sufficiently sophisticated society all work, so does a grain standard for setting prices against.

But I'm not actually sure you can get to the population densities you need for a Medieval/Renaissance society and technological base without metal, one of the biggest things about the Iron Age was the fact that humans started to be able to cultivate land that was previously inaccessible. Not a little bit of land, tens of thousands of square miles of land previously under impenetrable old-growth forest went under the plow in Europe and Asia. It changed the coastlines of whole continents, without those farms producing a surplus urbanisation would never have gotten started, specialisation and division of labour couldn't have progressed to any great degree because everyone would still be scrambling to eek out a living on the little pockets of good plow land around the edges. Unless you can break ground on the same kind of land another way, or have some super abundance of good farm land that the trees don't like you're a bit stuck.